# Find the nth highest

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT  CONCAT(C.CUSTOMER_FNAME, ' ',C.CUSTOMER_LNAME) AS FullNAME, SUM(QTY* PRICE)AS TOTAL_SPENDINGS

    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 TOTAL_SPENDINGS) RESULT

          Customers$ C INNER JOIN Invoices$ Inv ON C.CUSTOMER_ID=Inv.CUSTOMER_ID
          INNER JOIN InvDetails$ InvD ON Inv.INVOICE_ID=InvD.INVOICE_ID
          INNER JOIN Products$ P ON P.PRODUCT_ID=InvD.PRODUCT_ID

    GROUP BY  C.CUSTOMER_FNAME,C.CUSTOMER_LNAME
    ORDER BY TOTAL_SPENDINGS DESC
```

I am trying to prin the k-highest spending customers this is what i have done until now but i get

> Incorrect syntax near 'Customers$'.

Comment: You have many problems. Let's start with the first one - the derived table to which you gave the alias of RESULT. You attempt to select top 2 rows FROM WHAT? You also say you want the nth highest (but maybe the k-highest - what does that mean) yet you use TOP 2. Something does not match there. I suggest you start over and just compute the value you use to determine "highest spending" for every row. Once you have that, you can then get specific rows (probably using rank).

Answer (score 1):

**You are missing the join condition between the calculated table RESULT and the Customers table:**

```
SELECT  CONCAT(C.CUSTOMER_FNAME, ' ',C.CUSTOMER_LNAME) AS FullNAME, SUM(QTY* PRICE)AS TOTAL_SPENDINGS

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 TOTAL_SPENDINGS) RESULT
      <missing INNER / LEFT join here>
      Customers$ C <missing ON here>  INNER JOIN Invoices$ Inv ON C.CUSTOMER_ID=Inv.CUSTOMER_ID
      INNER JOIN InvDetails$ InvD ON Inv.INVOICE_ID=InvD.INVOICE_ID
      INNER JOIN Products$ P ON P.PRODUCT_ID=InvD.PRODUCT_ID

GROUP BY  C.CUSTOMER_FNAME,C.CUSTOMER_LNAME
ORDER BY TOTAL_SPENDINGS DESC
```

Comment: what should i put in the missing on ?

Comment: Not knowing your data structure it is hard to be sure.  If total_spendings is in the Customers$ table, then you probably just have the bracket in the wrong spot.